# Задача с промисами.Как решить?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```js
const item1 = {
    category: "cat_1",
    data: new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("This item number 1 from category 1"), 1000)
    }),
};

const item2 = {
    category: "cat_1",
    data: new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("This item number 2 from category 1"), 1000)
    }),
};
```

Я получаю вот такую data.Я должен все розпромисить и вернуть ответ.

```js
async function unPromise(input){
    const some =  Promise.all(input.filter((e) => {
        return new Promise(async(resole,reject) => {
            const res = await e.data
            console.log(res)
            return res
        }).then(res => e.data = res)
    }))
    some.then(data => console.log(data))
    console.log(some)
}
```

Я пробую сделать так но не работает(Есть у кого метод решения?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: item2 = {
    category: "cat_1",
    data:This item number 2 from category 
};